# Remove bleed from Pdf and merge

Tags: c#-4.0, pdf-generation, itext

```
   I am trying remove 3mm bleed size from pdf. by using below criteria
```

[image]

My source file is [Source file](http://docdro.id/e9Cw6qf)

I am using below code to trim left and right

```
    public void TrimLeftandRight(string sourceFilePath, string outputFilePath)
    {

        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(sourceFilePath);
        float width = (float)GetPDFwidth(sourceFilePath);
        float height = (float)GetPDFHeight(sourceFilePath);
        float widthTo_Trim = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(3);

   

        PdfRectangle rectrightside = new PdfRectangle(0, 0, width - widthTo_Trim, height);
        PdfRectangle rectLeftside = new PdfRectangle(widthTo_Trim, 0, width, height);

        //     int[] pagealignment = new int[] { 8, 1, 2, 7, 6, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] pagealignment = new int[] { 6, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3 };
        using (var output = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            // Create a new document
            Document doc = new Document();

            // Make a copy of the document
            PdfSmartCopy smartCopy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, output);

            // Open the newly created document
            doc.Open();

            // Loop through all pages of the source document
            for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                // Get a page
                var page = pdfReader.GetPageN(i);

                // Apply the rectangle filter we created

                switch (i)
                {
                    case 6:
                        page.Put(PdfName.CROPBOX, rectLeftside);
                        page.Put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, rectrightside);
                       
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        page.Put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, rectrightside);
                      
                        break;
                    case 4:

                        page.Put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, rectLeftside);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        page.Put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, rectLeftside);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        page.Put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, rectrightside);
                       // page.Put(PdfName.CROPBOX, rectLeftside);
                        break;
                    case 3:

                        page.Put(PdfName.CROPBOX, rectLeftside);
                        page.Put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, rectrightside);
                        break;

                }
                // Copy the content and insert into the new document
                var copiedPage = smartCopy.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, i);
                smartCopy.AddPage(copiedPage);
            }

            // Close the output document
            smartCopy.Close();
            doc.Close();
            doc.Dispose();

        }
    }
```

the output of above code produces
[Trimmed left and right file](http://docdro.id/LelbC5P)

and I used below code to merge trimmed files

```
    public void CreategateFinalOutput(string inputfile)
    {
        
        double widthinpoints = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(897);
        string onlyfilename = Path.GetFileName(inputfile);
        // string originalfilename = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + onlyfilename);
        int Noofpagesinpdf = GetNoofpagesofpdf(inputfile);
        //  var a3doc = new Document(PageSize.A3.Rotate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
        double originalwidth = GetPDFwidth(inputfile);

        float widthTo_Trim = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(3);
      
        double width = (GetPDFwidth(inputfile) * 3);
        width = widthinpoints;
        double height = GetPDFHeight(inputfile);
      
        var a3reader = new PdfReader(inputfile);
        var a3doc = new Document(new Rectangle((float)width, (float)height));
       
        var a3writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(a3doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/RP/" + onlyfilename), FileMode.Create));

        a3doc.Open();

        var a3cb = a3writer.DirectContent;

        PdfImportedPage page;

        int totalPages = a3reader.NumberOfPages;

        //  int[] pagealignment = new int[] { 8, 1, 2, 7, 6, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] pagealignment = new int[] { 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int iteration = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++)
        {
            a3doc.NewPage();
        
            var a3size = new Document(new Rectangle((float)width, (float)height));
            //new code
            int fistpage = 0;
            int secpage = 0;
            int thirdpage = 0;
            switch (iteration)
            {
                case 1:
                    fistpage = 5;
                    secpage = 6;
                    thirdpage = 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fistpage = 2;
                    secpage = 3;
                    thirdpage = 4;
                    break;
            }


                    double trimwidth = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(3);
                   
                    page = a3writer.GetImportedPage(a3reader, fistpage);
                    double pagewidth = page.Width;
                    a3cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

                    i++;

                    page = a3writer.GetImportedPage(a3reader, secpage);
                    double pagewidtha = page.Width;

                    a3cb.AddTemplate(page, (float)(pagewidtha), 0);

                    i++;

                    page = a3writer.GetImportedPage(a3reader, thirdpage);
                    double pagewidthaThird = page.Width;
                    // a3cb.AddTemplate(page, (int)(a3size.Width / 2), 0); //commented
                    a3cb.AddTemplate(page, (float)(pagewidthaThird + pagewidth), 0);
                    iteration++;
            

            a3doc.Close();
        }
    }
```

When i merged pdf by using above code the out put is not as per desire
[Final output](http://docdro.id/Ofi61n9)
Here we have removed borders of page 5 and 6 but when we merged there is border appearing .

You can see it downloading pdfs.. apologies for a such a big code. the help will be highly appreciated

I request to download pdfs and check pdfs for better views

Comment: Concerning `TrimLeftandRight`: For some pages you use the crop box to trim on one side and the media box to trim the other. This makes the crop box to go beyond the boundaries of the media box on one side. This is not valid according to the spec.

Comment: Concerning `CreategateFinalOutput`: `PdfWriter.GetImportedPage` imports the whole media box and ignores a smaller crop box. you need additional clipping.